# How do I play a midi file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, midi

I am trying to create a chrome extension that automatically plays midi files found on sites because the embed tag doesn't work for a lot of people. I have tried using midi.js from http://mudcu.be/midi-js/, but the documentation is unclear.

Here is my manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Auto Play Midi",
  "description": "This extension autoplays midi files",
  "version": "1.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["midi.js", "play_midi.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my javascript:

```
function play(){
    var embededs = document.getElementsByTagName("embed");
    var src;
    for (var i = 0; i < embededs.length; i++) {
        src = embededs[i].getAttribute("src");
        if(src.slice(-5) == ".midi" || src.slice(-4) == ".mid"){
            MIDI.Player.loadFile(src);
            MIDI.Player.start();
        }
    }
}

window.onload = play;
```

Comment: Take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/eu5ewcj2/ and https://jsfiddle.net/bL732go5/